# Is there a different understanding of "rubber" in British and American English?

Tags: word-choice, nouns, american-english, british-english

I was well aware of the different meanings of *rubber*, not least because there are the same definitions in my mother-tongue. However, while reading a text about differences between British and American English I read the following lines:

> Here's something else for Americans to be aware of: did you know that an *eraser* is called a *rubber* in Britain? A good British Mum makes sure her children go to school with a rubber in their pencil case.

So, it's also not new to me that there are differences between British English and American English, but I was and still am surprised that that could somehow be misinterpreted.

Checking the dictionary ([OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/rubber) and [OED](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rubber?q=rubber)) I learned that *rubber* as *condom* is indeed an Americanism, though I can hardly believe that British people do not know/use that word.

The other way round, I can imagine to some extent that Americans are not aware of the fact that it isn't that popularly known/used in British English.

Anyway, when talking to British people do I really have to expect that they don't know what I'm talking about when using the word *rubber* instead of *condom*?

And when talking to American people, should I avoid *rubber* and use *eraser* instead whenever I expect it might sound ambiguous? To be more concrete: the OALD designates rubber (as eraser) as British English, thus do I have to suspect that an American may not be aware of that meaning?

Finally, when talking to both an American and a British at the same time, which words do I use for condom and eraser so that both will understand me correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure about the British perspective, but as an American, I would be surprised if you asked me for a rubber and were expecting an eraser.

Comment: In AmE used by much older people, 'rubber' can also refer to 'galoshes' (rubber anti-water shoe cover). Lots of embarassed laughs by the young whippersnappers. Really, does any of this come up in conversation anymore?

Comment: At whoever voted for close as general reference: I really like to see that link to "to the standard Internet reference source that can definitively and permanently answer that question" about usages and different connotations in two dialects.

Comment: As an Australian, using "rubber" to mean "condom" just sounds weird. Rubber and eraser are interchangeable. I don't know if that's just the area I grew up in or a more Australia-wide thing, though.

Comment: @AlbeyAmakiir, in Australia isn't Durex adhesive tape? Which would probably lead to even more confusion to a Brit !

Comment: @mgb, not that I'm aware. But I agree. We have our own weirdness in language. Even moving from Adelaide to Sydney, I'm finding not all my words mean the same thing!

Comment: As an American, I haven't heard anyone use "rubber" for "condom" in twenty years. I expect that many Americans would understand it in context, but for most of us I think "condom" is nearly as far down the list of possible definitions of "rubber" as "eraser" would be.

Comment: I have to disagree with @Caleb. My first thought when I hear rubber used as a countable noun is of a condom. I remember a time I was talking about a silicone bike seat and I wanted to compare it (although inaccurately) as a type of rubber and I said "It's like a rubber." and everyone who heard it had the same connotation and we all had an embarrassed laugh about it. (Oh, but that WAS more than 20 years ago. _Am I really that old?_)

Comment: Two countries divided by their common language. Americans wear fanny packs, English ask hotelliers to knock them up in the morning... there's an endless supply of innuendo drawn from differing uses of the same words.

Comment: In my experience, rubber is preferred to eraser in Australia, although both are understood to mean the same thing. And a condom is a condom.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Anyway, when talking to British people do I really have to expect that
> they don't know what I'm talking about when using the word rubber
> instead of condom?

Yes. That definition of rubber is not really used in the UK. Some people would know it from personal experiences of Americans. Like me. I know it because I have met some Americans in the UK and this word came up in the context of meeting one of them: in primary school, there was an American pupil in the last year. This definition would not generally, be reliable in the UK.

> And when talking to American people, should I avoid rubber and use
> eraser instead whenever I expect it might sound ambiguous? To be more
> concrete: the OALD designates rubber (as eraser) as British English,
> thus do I have to suspect that an American may not be aware of that
> meaning?

That would be the most reliable approach. As you can see from this discussion, there are some Americans who are aware of the British meaning of rubber but it is not used in the USA. Because of this, it is unreliable in the USA and many Americans might not know this meaning. When talking to Americans, it would be best to use the American word, eraser.

> Finally, when talking to both an American and a British at the same
> time, which words do I use for condom and eraser so that both will
> understand me correctly?

For a condom, just use the word condom. This is the proper word used in the UK and the USA. As the following links show, using the word rubber to mean a condom, is American slang:

> US slang  for a condom ([Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/rubber_1?q=rubber))
>
> [countable] American English informal a condom ([Longman Dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/rubber))

And the USA has this slang for the word, as well as the word itself.

For the word eraser, there will have to be a different kind of answer. This is an example of, one of the many differences in American English. Because the word eraser is not generally, reliable in the UK, it is not certain that any, particular British person, will know its American meaning. Whether or not it will be understood, will depend on which, particular British people you talk to.

If you talk to an American person and a British person at the same time, just use the word condom. It is understood in both countries.

Regarding eraser, you have a few possibilities. If you find out first, that one of the two knows the word used in the other's country; you can use a sentence that has just that word. For example, if you knew that the American person knows the British meaning of rubber, you can use just that. It could be that you are writing with a pencil and want to change some of the writing. You could ask, "have you got a rubber?". If you don't know in advance whether one of the two knows the word used in the other's country; you would need to use a sentence that covers both words. For example, you could ask "have you got a rubber/eraser?". You could also find out by asking, when you talk to them.

Comment: As a Brit, I'd be extremely surprised if someone didn't know that rubber could be used as a word for condom or if someone didn't know that eraser referred to a rubber (apart from anything else, pencil eraser is the proper term for them here - http://www.staples.co.uk/erasers/cbk/406.html ).

Comment: @JackAidley - Yes, you'd think "pencil eraser" would at the absolute least be understood simply from the meaning of those words.

Comment: @JackAidley Well I didn't until a few years ago. Thankfully it never became a problem for me. At the same time Americans don't know words like tosser. Oh I'm sure some do but many do not. They typically don't know the word knackered either. Otoh I think they mostly know what knickers are. At the same time though they don't know the difference between pants (the clothing and the other meaning) and trousers.

Comment: It's easy to assume people know all the same things you do, and if you as e.g. a young male white English college student meet a young male white American college student, you will have a lot in common in terms of cultural knowledge and experiences. But as you meet different people with different life experiences, then the differences mount.

Answer (score 16):

As far as British English is concerned, a rubber is normally an eraser (unless the context specifically indicates otherwise). Using the word for a condom is not unknown; but the usual "rubber" epithet for that is *rubber johnny*. Having said that, the word *condom* is far more likely to be used to refer to a condom than any other term. The Government started using "condom" in anti-AIDS advertising in 1987 and it's now acceptable and mainstream with no euphemisms needed.

Received wisdom on this side of the Atlantic is that *rubber* should not be used in the New World if you mean "eraser", because you don't remove pencil marks with a condom. I'm sure a native American English speaker will say what the right words are on their side of the ocean.

Comment: For AmE, 'eraser' for the thing that removes pencil marks on paper. Usually 'condom' for the prophylactic of procreation; colloquially, 'rubber'.

Comment: Oddly, the question calls for a word to "use for both an eraser and a condom" instead of separate words for each.

Comment: @jwpat7 Hmm. You're right. Obviously the answer to *that* is "rubber". I read that as "words", I think. Rule 1: Always read the question. Perhaps it should say "words".

Comment: I think this is another one of those contexts like *pissed*, where quite a few Americans are unaware of (or surprised by) the British meaning (drunk), but most Brits know the American one (angry), and don't see anything odd about a slang word having two different meanings. I suppose that's partly because there are more Americans, so their language variants dominate global media. But I do often get a sense that Americans on average are more likely to think words can *only* have those meanings sanctioned by (US) dictionaries.

Comment: @Fumble: I think you merely notice the one more than the other.  Even on english.se there have been many instances where UK participants have been astonished by common American words, meanings, and pronunciations.

Comment: @jwpat7 Edited my question since I haven't noticed that the last sentence could create misconceptions. Hopefully it is clearer now. And the missing s was a typo, so Andrew understood me correctly. So, actually I'm looking for two different words that are unambiguously and that I can use when talking to both at once.

Comment: @Em1 In that case, those words are *eraser* and *condom*. But using *eraser* in Britain would cause people to wonder why you didn't say "rubber" like everyone else.

Comment: +1 for the comment about AIDS awareness. Before that "condom" was rarely used in popular speech and lots of euphemisms were used. After the extremely widespread information campaign you'd sound odd using a euphemism.

Comment: @GEdgar are they astonished or are they just telling you proper English? ;)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Good analogy yes. I thought American *pissed* as in angry was just a shortening of *pissed off* but apparently it's not. This is why I tend to say *pissed drunk* rather than *pissed*. I don't use it very often since I don't like alcohol (or even being near any) but at least for that one there's an easy way to work out the problem.

Answer (score 10):

My experience indicates that Americans frequently misunderstand the use of "rubber" - even in a classroom setting, where erasers are quite common and condoms often less common. I grew up in Hong Kong and the USA, and asked a classmate in the USA if I could "borrow [his] rubber". I received odd looks from him and nearby classmates, and clarified with "eraser". I have related this story as a humorous anecdote on a number of occasions, and often surprise most people here in the states when I state my request to borrow a "rubber" - this indicates to me that it is not commonly understood by many Americans. As such, I would prefer "eraser" over "rubber" to avoid derailing a conversation or request.

Comment: The fact that an American is in a classroom setting doesn't change the fact that *eraser* is simply not a commonly recognized way to interpret *rubber* in American English, just as *public school* would never mean "elite independent school" instead of "traditional government-funded school" and *car valeting* would never mean "thorough cleaning and polishing of a car" instead of "working as an attendant who parks cars for customers."

Comment: @choster are you indicating extraneous information?

Comment: I am saying that the American reaction is not a "misunderstanding" as in as taking one meaning for another. There is only one familiar meaning of *rubber* in American English.

Comment: @choster - Actually, "rubber" is quite commonly used (with no smirks) when discussing car tires.  So there are at least two different meanings.  (And did I ever tell you I used to test rubbers for the Air Force?)

Comment: @HotLicks Exactly how often does anyone, regardless of dialect, ask to borrow a car tire in a classroom setting? Context is everything.

Comment: @choster - You meant to say that there is only one likely meaning of *rubber* *if used (between students) in an American classroom*.

Comment: @HotLicks My original comments are on liridayn's response, which posits a classroom scenario, and in any case the point is that American English is not a "misunderstanding" of any other kind of English.

Comment: @HotLicks the fact that tires are made of (synthetic) rubber (and a bunch of other things) in no way means that I just bought two new *rubbers* for our Camry.

Answer (score 10):

I think, from the variants presented in these answers, that the answer to your final question is simple. If you're aiming for maximum clarity, use "condom" for condoms, "eraser" for erasers, and skip the ambiguous "rubber" altogether.

That is, *if* you're aiming for clarity. :)

Comment: I agree with you about the word condom. Rubber is not really ambiguous, if you know and understand the difference in American and British English. If you do, it's just a matter of using the word appropriately for your audience.

Comment: See the OP's last question: "when talking to both an American and a British at the same time", this will remove ambiguities. Also, if you're talking to someone who's neither British nor American, and you're not sure where he gets his vocabulary.

Comment: Whether or not it will remove ambiguity, will depend heavily on whether the particular, British person would know the word eraser. Eraser is American English and not really used in the UK, which already has a literally English word for it: rubber. That would be an assumption to say that you would have clarity, when using this word with British people.

Comment: Regarding talking to someone who's neither British nor American. That would also be an assumption to say that you should only use one word, eraser or rubber. Not everyone in the world who learns English, learns American English. There are different possibilities for such a situation. Either find out in advance, if they know the American word or; use a sentence that covers both words. You could also find out by asking, when you talk to them.

Comment: *rubber* may be the British word, but even if faced with the new and unfamiliar word *eraser*, it would be relatively easy to understand it, since it's rather simply constructed from its function - *to erase*. The opposite is not true - an American stumbling into *rubber* will have a harder time gleaning its meaning, since the meaning of "something that rubs" is lost in the second meaning, that of the material rubber.

Comment: To think that it would be relatively easy to understand it, would be an assumption. I know from my primary school experience, that this was not the case. When an eraser was asked for by the American pupil, I and the other children at the table asked "what's that?". They then explained by saying what it was for. It's not guaranteed that all British people would know that word. It's worth remembering that American English is not the language of England, or the rest of the UK.

Comment: Well, of course it isn't. That's what this whole question and thread is about.

Comment: Good point, "Eraser" is not ambiguous because it is either understood directly or not understood, whereas "Rubber" is ambiguous since it could mean two different things to different people. It's better for someone to not understand, than to misunderstand.

Comment: I agree with this answer. American English has become the _lingua franca_ of English whether those of us who are not American like it or not. Personally, as a speaker of Australian English, I grew up saying _rubber_, but now I just say _eraser_. But I say it in a ridiculous American accent as that amuses me.

Comment: Using "pencil eraser" rather than "eraser" would likely help with the understanding of the term when the listener is not familiar with it.

Answer (score 2):

Why is solid latex known as *rubber*? Because of its ability to rub out pencil marks! That being the case, there should be no embarrassment in asking someone for a rubber.

Comment: Quite true. I have the distinct feeling that many decades ago I had teachers who referred to erasers as **India rubbers** to head off potential schoolboy sniggers. But that was Britain, where mostly we called the other ones *johnnies* rather than *rubber johnnies*. I've no idea why we chose to discard a different word from each pair, rather than the same one.

Answer (score 2):

Also, American slang for a hospital gown is "Johnny", so English people in US hospitals should be aware that if a nurse asks you to put on a "Johnny", it's probably a mistake to slip on a condom.

Comment: Haha! I never knew that.

Comment: I've never heard that, and have been a American for a *long* time.  (All my life, in fact.)  Since I won't assume you're lying, it must be a regional term.

Comment: That needs some documentation. I can see patients asking for the item and being embarrassed.

Answer (score 1):

> Anyway, when talking to British people do I really have to expect that
>   they don't know what I'm talking about when using the word rubber
>   instead of condom?

I'm a Brit living close to London, so I can help with this one.

In the UK, "Rubber" and "Johnny" are the two most popular colloquialisms for Condom. Johnny is more common today - Rubber is more of a nineties term.

However, our first understanding of a "Rubber" is an "Eraser". We do not use the term "Eraser".

If you ask a man in the street for a Rubber, he will think you are talking about an Eraser.

If you ask him in a Club, well... :-)

Comment: What happened to "raincoat" as euphemism for condom?

Answer (score 0):

In general, lots of words have multiple meanings. Sometimes it's obvious which meaning is meant by the context, sometimes it's not and the sentence is confusing. Lots of words have different meanings in different dialects. As anything related to sex is often an awkward subject, we often use euphemisms to talk about sex, giving yet more meanings to other words.

So yes, as an American, to me the word "rubber" can mean the soft, pliable material that comes from rubber plants, the synthetic substance made from petroleum products to behave like rubber, car tires, condoms, something to do with the card game Bridge, maybe other meanings. I'm aware of the British use to mean "eraser" but that is not a meaning that would normally come to mind.

By the way, many jokes are based on exactly this sort of ambiguity. The comedian will say that someone said X, and it's obvious what the intended meaning is, and then he says that another person replied Y, indicating that he had interpreted the word differently. If it's done well it can be funny.

If I was at a car dealership looking to buy a used car and the salesman said, "If you want this car, we can give you new rubber at no extra charge", I'd surely understand him to mean that they'd put new tires on the car, not that they'd give me a condom. If I was listening to a lecture on prostitution and the speaker said, "Some prostitutes insist that their client use a rubber to protect themselves from STDs", I would surely understand him to mean a condom and not an eraser. Etc.

If you want to avoid ambiguity, avoid words that have double meanings, or add enough words to clarify. Like say, "a rubber eraser" instead of just, "a rubber". Of course, given the large number of words that are used as euphemisms for sex, avoiding this sort of double meaning can be difficult. I think in most cases, people would know what you meant, though they might snicker at the double meaning.